# How do I get the Karuma armoured car?

Tags: grand-theft-auto-online

I want to drive the Karuma armoured car, but I'm not sure how to get it. Does anyone know?

Answer (score 3):

The [Wiki](http://gta.wikia.com/wiki/Kuruma_(Armored)) states that it can be bought after completing the first heist in the Heist update:

> Can be purchased from Southern San Andreas Super Autos for $525,000 after completing The Fleeca Job.

Comment: You can complete the heist either as host OR as guest, you just need to participate in the Heist finale, it's a 2-person mission, super easy.